# Unable to add Digital ID's in Adobe Reader for Pdf Signing. Self signed certificate are created using Openssl version 3.1.3 in windows machine

Tags: windows, openssl, digital-signature, ubuntu-22.04, adobe-reader

Unable to add Digital ID's in Adobe Reader for Pdf Signing. Getting error "Could not open digital ID with the password provided. Try again.". We verified the password is correct, but still getting exception. Self signed digital id was generated using Openssl v3.1.3. But the certificate generated using Openssl V1.1.1 works fine.

Error details:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y1F1.png)

Using below commands to generate the PKCS12 certificate in both versions.

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.key -aes256
openssl req -new -key private.key -out csr.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.csr -signkey private.key -out certificate.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt

Compared both the certificates, Could not find any difference except the serial key length.